# Show that $f(x)=\cos(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am not sure how to proceed. Should I rewrite $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=|2\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}|$?

Comment: Hint: You could try to prove that $\cos x $ is Lipschitz by using the mean value theorem.

Comment: It would also help if you used the correct identity. What you wrote down is the sum-to-product formula for $\cos x+\cos y$.

Comment: Try the derivative form of Lipschitz condition. i.e. $|\frac{df}{dx}|\le 1,\forall x\in Dom(f)$

Comment: Do i write $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=|\cos'(x)||x-y|$, by the mean value theorem, then $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=|\cos'(x)||x-y|=|-\sin(x)||x-y|=\sin(x)|x-y|$, where $\sin(x)$ is bounded by 1?

Comment: @universekid8: yes, except it should be $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=|\cos'(c)||x-y|$, where $c$ is in $(x,y)$. There is no reason that $c=x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is a $c \in (x,y)$ such that $$\textrm{cos}(x)-\textrm{cos}(y)=(-\textrm{sin}(c))(x-y).$$

So we have that $$|\textrm{cos}(x)-\textrm{cos}(y)|=|(-\textrm{sin}(c))(x-y)| \leq 1 \cdot |x-y|.$$

Thus $f(x)=\textrm{cos}(x)$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3):

For all $x$, $|\sin x|\leq |x|$. Using Sum to Product formula:

$|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=\left|-2\sin\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)\;\sin\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\leq2\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\leq2\left|\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right|=|x-y|$

Comment: Don't we have to show that the function is Lipschitz continuous if there is $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq(C|x-y|)$? Or do we just conclude that $C=1$?

Comment: @universekid8 : Yes, C=$1$

Comment: $|\sin x|\le|x|$ for ALL $x$, not only for "small" ones (which has no sense in maths).

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS : My bad. I wished to write "all" not "small".

Answer (score 3):

A function with bounded derivative is *always* Lipschitz continuous, for we have

$\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert = \left \vert \displaystyle \int_x^y f'(s) \; ds \right \vert \le \left \vert \displaystyle \int_x^y \vert f'(s) \vert \; ds \right \vert; \tag 1$

if now

$\vert f'(s) \vert \le M, \tag 2$

then

$\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \le \left \vert \displaystyle \int_x^y \vert f'(s) \vert \; ds \right \vert \le \left \vert \displaystyle \int_x^y M \; ds \right \vert \le M \vert y - x \vert, \tag 3$

which shows that $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant at most $M$.

Since

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; \vert (\cos x)' \vert = \vert \sin x \vert \le 1, \tag 4$

it follows that $\cos x$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant at most $1$.