# Convergence rate of $\sum_{k=1}^nc_{n,k}x_k$, where $c_{n,k}\to0$ for each $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to obtain an upper bound on the convergence rate of the sequence
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^nc_{n,k}x_k
=\sum_{k=1}^n\biggl|\frac1q\sum_{j=1}^q\cos\Bigl(\frac{2\pi kj}n\Bigr)-1\biggr|x_k\tag{1},
\end{equation}
where $x_k$'s are non-negative and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k<\infty$ while $q=q_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ but $q/n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Using the [Lipschitz continuity of the cosine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3135803/23249),
\begin{equation}
c_{n,k}
\le\frac{2\pi k}{qn}\sum_{j=1}^qj\tag{2}
=\pi k\Bigl(\frac qn+\frac1n\Bigr)
\end{equation}
which shows that $c_{n,k}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each fixed $k\ge1$. The dominated convergence theorem then implies that sequence (1) converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. However, if we use inequality (2) to bound sequence (1), we get the bound
$$
\pi\Bigl(\frac qn+\frac1n\Bigr)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx_k,
$$
which might not even go to $0$.

> How can we obtain an upper bound on the convergence rate of (1)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Bound $(2)$ implies $c_{n,k}\sim qk/n$, we show this can be improved to $c_{n,k}\sim(qk/n)^2$.

Let $z=\pi k/n$ , by [this formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+cos%28jx%29+j%3D1+to+q) for $\sum_j\cos(jz)$ we have

$$c_{n,k}=\left|\frac{\sin(qz)}{q\sin(z)}\cos((q+1)z)-1\right|.$$

For $k\leq n/(4q)$, we have $0\leq\sin(qz)\leq q\sin(z)$ and $\cos((q+1)z)\in[0,1]$, these imply that

$$c_{n,k}\leq\Big(1-\cos((q+1)z)\Big)+\left(1-\frac{\sin(qz)}{q\sin(z)}\right).$$

Using the Taylor-series bounds $y-y^3/6\leq\sin(y)\leq y$ and $\cos(y)\geq1-y^2/2$, it follows

$$c_{n,k}\leq\frac12(q+1)^2z^2+\frac16q^2z^2\leq30(qk/n)^2.$$

---

Now $c_{n,k}\leq30(qk/n)^2$ when $k\leq n/(4q)$, along with the uniform bound $c_{n,k}\leq2$ we have
$$\frac1{30}\sum_{k=1}^nc_{n,k}x_k\leq(q/n)^2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/(4q)\rfloor}k^2x_k+\sum_{k=\lfloor n/(4q)\rfloor+1}^nx_k. \tag{$\star$}$$

I think we cannot further improve the bound qualitatively because

- we don't know how fast $\sum x_k$ converges,
- the [Taylor series of $c_{n,k}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+1-sin%28q*pi*k%2Fn%29%2F%28q*sin%28pi*k%2Fn%29%29cos%28%28q%2B1%29*pi*k%2Fn%29+at+n%3Dinf) is $(qk/n)^2+\mathcal O((qk/n)^4)$ at $n=\infty$.

---

If we know how fast $x_k\to0$, then by ($\star$) we can work out the convergence rate of $S_n=\sum_kc_{n,k}x_k$. Here are some examples:

- If $x_k$ decays faster than $k^{-s}$ for any $s>3$, then $S_n\sim(q/n)^2$
- If $x_k\sim k^{-3}$, then $S_n\sim(q/n)^2\ln(n/q)$
- If $x_k\sim k^{-s}$ for $s\in(1,3)$, then $S_n\sim(q/n)^{1-s}$

As we can see, the lower bound of the asymptotic decay is $(q/n)^2$, while the upper bound is $1$ (not decay to $0$) since $S_n$ can decay as slowly as we want by letting $x_k\to0$ slowly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very helpful (+1)! (1) How did you decide to choose the power of $1/4$ (the minimum is equal to $qk/n$ when $k<n/q$ but we can use either of the two bounds for any $k\ge1$ as far as I understand)? (2) Can we say something about the convergence rate of  $\sum_{k=\lfloor(n/q)^{1/4}\rfloor}^\infty x_k$?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Sorry I was editing the post when I saw your comment, I will simply respond your questions in the updated answer.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Sorry this took longer than expected, it seems we can get quadratic decay in $q/n$, so I rewrote the whole post. Let me know in case there are mistakes, thanks!